# Django ORM: Why would Django use SELECT (1) on its own?

Tags: python, sql, django, sqlite

When using Django (with SQLite3) I noticed the following query in `connection.queries` :

```
"sql": "SELECT (1) AS \"a\" FROM \"blog_comment\" WHERE \"blog_comment\".\"id\" = 5  LIMIT 1"
```

I understand *what* the query does (just returns the first column from each matching row), but why do this?

Is it just an inexpensive way of checking for EXISTS in SQLite3? If so, in what context would it be used on its own?

Comment: @gbn - I'm not sure I even understand that question (I apologize, if due to my lack of SQL knowledge, I'm unable to provide more detail)

Comment: I checked the SQLite docs and it is a constant 1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is just checking for existence of rows.
 
It doesn't have any meaning otherwise because "1" is a constant value